# onclick event don't work on WEB page

Tags: javascript, css, html, user-interface

I want to create a modal box. It should appear, when a user clicks a button, and close, when the user clicks a close button in the modal box. 
I made two functions:

- check() : it change css. After it's elememt onclick, appears modal box
- close() : this function should close modal box, but it doesm't. It simply should set previous css setting. This function isn't execution at all when I click a close button(span element).

Why close function doesn't work and what I should modernize to get a result?

Thanks in advance)

```js
function check() {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
//this function dont't work
function close(){
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}


.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <button id="button" type="submit" onclick="check()">Login</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content" >
      <span class="close" onclick="close()">&times;</span>
      <p >Some text in the Modal..</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`close` is already the name of a native browser function, `window.close()`. Rename your function and it works fine:

```js
function check() {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal(){
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}


.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <button id="button" type="submit" onclick="check()">Login</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content" >
      <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
      <p >Some text in the Modal..</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```